# Upgrade SQL CE 2.0 database to SQL CE 3.5 database

Tags: compact-framework, sql-server-ce, upgrade

Has anybody performed the upgrade?

If yes, how is it done. I remember tinkering with running a program on command line on the PDA and that it did not work as expected.

Has running the command line program on the PDA worked for anyone?

Comment: You need to work on your avatar, you smelly little man. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for posting the question. We were able to upgrade the project using the method below.
We had to copy the upgrade.exe to the PDA tough.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
@"\Program Files\client\upgrade.exe"
, @"/s ""\Program Files\client\database.sdf"" /sp ""password"" /d ""\Program Files\client\convertedDB.sdf"" /dp ""password"" /e /q");
```

Hopefully someone finds this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this programmatically, why hack using the Upgrade utility?  Why not just use the [Upgrade method present in the SqlCeEngine class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceengine.upgrade.aspx)?

Comment: Because the Upgrade api only upgrades from 3.1 to 3.5. That would be the step after running upgrade.exe